# Why does debugger ask me to eject again?

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome-devtools, jestjs, create-react-app

I am getting my head around create-react-app and just tried the eject option. After 'yarn eject' I am trying to debug via the terminal:

```
> react-scripts --inspect-brk test --runInBand

Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:9229/45316de1-972e-47ab-9ce8-7ce2f183a378
For help, see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
Debugger attached.
```

when clicking on the inspect link in the chrome://inspect/#devices, the console opens and says:

> Out of the box, Create React App only supports overriding these Jest
>   options:  • collectCoverageFrom  • coverageReporters  •
>   coverageThreshold  • globalSetup  • globalTeardown  • resetMocks  •
>   resetModules  • snapshotSerializers  • watchPathIgnorePatterns.These
>   options in your package.json Jest configuration are not currently
>   supported by Create React App:  • resolver  • setupFiles  • testMatch 
>   • testEnvironment  • testURL  • transform  • transformIgnorePatterns 
>   • moduleNameMapper  • moduleFileExtensionsIf you wish to override
>   other Jest options, you need to eject from the default setup. You can
>   do so by running npm run eject but remember that this is a one-way
>   operation. You may also file an issue with Create React App to discuss
>   supporting more options out of the box.

That is strange because I thought I already ran the eject?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`react-scripts` is the executable that unejected `create-react-app` runs, so it will produce this message, no matter whether the project was ejected or not.

`npm run eject` replaces `react-scripts` in ejected project `scripts` with actual commands. In ejected project, it is expected that `npm run test` executes `jest` directly instead of `react-scripts test`.

If the intention is to provide additional arguments to Node, it could be something like:

```
node --inspect-brk node_modules/.bin/jest test --runInBand
```

Comment: Any alternatives to chrome / jest to debug js unit tests?

Comment: I would go with Chrome. Usually I have no need to debug it if unit tests are isolated and contain enough assertions. A value you may want to debug is listed in case an assertion fails. You won't be able to debug Jest if it runs remotely with CI, but you will need to figure out what's wrong from the report.